# Laravel mysql join issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 tables both the table have exact same field names and datatype.

ISSUES:
1) I'm unable to receive data from both columns
2) I also need to count phone no in both table

The field names are member_id, name , phone

```
`SAMPLE DATA IN MEMBER TABLE`
------------------------------
member_id | name | phone     |
------------------------------
100000    | ABC | 9876543210 |
-----------------------------*

`NOW SAMPLE DATA IN MEMBER_TEMP TABLE`
------------------------------
member_id | name | phone     |
------------------------------
100001    | DEF | 9876543210 |
-----------------------------*

`NOW EXPECTED RESULTS/ OUTPUT EXPECTED`
------------------------------
member_id | name | phone     |
------------------------------
100000    | ABC | 9876543210 |
------------------------------
100001    | DEF | 9876543210 |
-----------------------------*
```

BELOW IS LARAVEL QUERY BUILDER

```
$member_info = DB::table('member')->select('member_temp.*','member.*')->where(
            array(
            )
    );

    $member_info = $member_info->join('member_temp','member_temp.phone', '=', 'member.phone')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

//RAW MYSQL QUERY

```
select *
from `member`
inner join `member_temp`
    on `member_temp`.`phone` = `member`.`phone`
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Please include the raw MySQL query you want to use.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen please check i have updated my question

Comment: Is that the actual MySQL query you want to run?  What about the counts?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen as mentioned i need to take `result OR Count` of matching phone number from both table. When i run the query i get only one result from a particular table

Comment: Please include sample data for both tables, along with the expected output.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen sure

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen i have included data for both table and expected result

Comment: Are you sure you need a join and not a union?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should use eloquent model to get phone column from both tables. it will always conflict in fluent query(join) because of same column name

Answer (score 1):

I think you have started out with the wrong raw sql query.

It seems like you are looking for something more like this to get all the data you want out of the database:

```
select a.memberid as MemberId, b.memberid as MemberTempId, a.name as MemberName, 
b.name as MemberTempName, a.phone from member as a join member_temp as b on 
member.phone = member_temp.phone;
```